# Custom Lexer in wxscintilla

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Hello guys can some body tell me how to implement a simple lexer in wxscintilla so that i can highlight a simple word like "sbit" or any other specified word. Using the inbuilt highlight identifier would high light even non keyword words. I am using c++ wxWidgets. My code is like this

m_scintilla1->SetLexer(wxSCI_LEX_CPP);

m_scintilla1->StyleSetForeground (20, wxColour (_T("BLUE")));

m_scintilla1->SetKeyWords(20,_("sbit"));

the above code wont work. Any help.

Comment: OK. No wxScintilla guyz in stackover flow

Answer (score 0):

```
m_scintilla1->SetKeyWords(20,_("sbit"));
```

The ID here must be 0 or 1. You have 2 Keyword-sets for every lexer, 0 and 1.

See a sample here, from my ShaderDesigner. I have setup a coloration for glsl (mis)using the cpp-lexer:
http://code.google.com/p/nightlight2d/source/browse/trunk/NightShade/SourceEdit.cpp#30
HTH